# Can ClickOnce install a single DLL for registration on end machine?

Tags: installation, clickonce

I wrote a DLL (with a COM interface) and wonder if I can use ClickOnce to deploy it on end-user machines (to be called using CreateObject("My.DllClass") from the user VBasic app. All the documentation that I've read for ClickOnce (and the abortive attempts that I've made) seem to indicate that a real app (exe, etc) is required for ClickOnce -- it can't deploy a single DLL (and some txt files) and get the DLL registered for COM use on the target machine.

Q1. Is my understanding correct?
Q2. Is my best alternative to learn the Wix Installer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Yes, your ClickOnce application must have at least one launchable executable file. It's minimal requirement. But you can add any .net executable file there.
Q2: Yes/no. I will try to describe some things for you here. It'll let you make a right decision in your choose. Here is my point of view your task if you gonna choose a ClickOnce technology.

`Abbreviate: ClickOnce application = Your.dll + dotNet-Some.exe`

1. At the first you need to know a ClickOnce application locating in `Users\[CurrentUser]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0` after get installed by user. You can't effect on location, so if your client PC have more then one users, then second one must install your application for your self again. As me know your COM assembly must be registered by `regasm.exe`, there for your `Some.exe` can on launch register your dll by `regasm.exe` or some `WinAPI` functionality, so executable file won't be useless in this way.
2. Major question is update process, you must track your clickonce build number at the first, and for update operation user must launch your `Some.exe` for check and now workarounds from here. If this update process if fine, then you need re-register your assembly again (because clickonce add new folder for updated assembly) and user will be ready for use your class.

In the case of MSI package you have full control of install process, but you need always deliver this packages to your clients. Wix is good, if you are .NET developer take a look on WixSharp - let you create installer much more faster and have a lot of examples

If you don't gonna publish your ClickOnce application from Visual Studio then you can use Mage.exe / MageUI.exe for ClickOnce application preparation or use my builder utility from here [second download link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mage-exe-manifest-generation-and-editing-tool).

I hope what i said was a bit useful.

Comment: Thank you Sergey, yes, your answer was very useful, and I see that the exe file would do the registering for COM. Would the user have the administrator rights to do the registration from the exe? I will have a look at WixSharp for sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, your application will have user permissions. But you can set administrator level requirement from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator). Your executable file will ask user for elevate rights for run with log as dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comment. I gave up on the click once mechanism and have decided to go the traditional MSI route.